# Long precompilation time for Julia package

Tags: package, julia

i’ve created a new package named QuantumRelay, and i’m putting all the files that i need for this package in one file and everything and i’ve added also all the dependencies needed and when i’m typing
`using QuantumRelay` all i’m getting is this precompiling message : `Info: Precompiling QuantumRelay [54a2c7e4-e504-11e9-3c64-f9d4f875ee7f]` i’ve been waiting for more than 30 minutes for julia to give me the hand again so i can call the functions in this module but till now, no result.

The Julia package source is here: [Quantum_Relay](https://github.com/marouanehanhasse/Quantum_Relay)

Comment: Can you post the code or push it to a public repository? You likely have an infinite loop or something.

Comment: yes sure. https://github.com/marouanehanhasse/Quantum_Relay

Comment: I tried to download your package and install all the dependencies, but I'm getting

```(QuantumRelay.jl) pkg> add Clp
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package LinQuadOptInterface [f8899e07]:
 LinQuadOptInterface [f8899e07] log:
```. Can you please add a Project.toml and Manifest.toml as well? That way we can reproduce the build.

Comment: As @fredrikekre stated I have been observing the same thing. Sometimes when we have circular dependencies between local modules the Julia Compiler never stops. Not sure if it is an issue in 1.2, I guess you can check if you have a circular dependency somewhere

Comment: @JKRT i'm tryied to locate some infinite loop or something like that but everything seem fine to me .

Comment: @kdheepak Clp has not been updated to the latest JuMP version. Use JuMP 0.19 so Clp will be installed by ```add JuMP@0.19```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that precompiling this package on julia 1.0 is not working cause, it's taking forever, however if we use the 1.3 julia version it precompiles even though this version is not stable yet but it's working.